# jni accessing jobjectArray from jobject

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have jobject and its has jobjectArray inside ,I am using GetObjectField to get jobjectArray and then casting it , but its not working can anyone help ?

---

```
 jfieldID representationArrayF = env->GetFieldID(className, "representationArray", "[Lcodec/video/initial/MMRepresentation");
 jobject objectArr=(jobject)env->GetObjectField(jpresentationInfo, representationArrayF);
 jobjectArray*  objectArray=reinterpret_cast<jobjectArray*>(&objectArr);
 jobject representation=(jobject) env->GetObjectArrayElement(*objectArray, i)
```

Comment: Take a look here for accessing object info: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-020/ and here, to get the feeling of passing arrays between Java and C: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo026

Comment: what should work? and whats happening?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos  I am getting error [ V  [libjvm.so+0x6de77c]  jni_GetObjectArrayElement+0xcc]   while GetObjectArrayElement(*objectArray, 0)

Answer (score 0):

it is silly mistake which is fine with simple parameters but with array parameters it not working instead of [Lcodec/video/initial/MMRepresentation , i have to put [Lcodec/video/initial/MMRepresentation;  semicolon at end

don't know with simple parameters like III  semicolon is not necessary

Comment: Moral: don't guess. Use the output of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this :)

Comment: All objects needs the 'L + full path name + ;' only primitives have their values